# Problem using .load function in Node Repl

Tags: node.js

I am running Nodejs and trying to load a script in repl using:
.load transformscript.js

The first two lines in transformscript.js are as below:
`.load rdfMapping.js` `.load rdfVocab.js`

The problem is that I am getting the error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token .' on the first line. Does someone have any idea why this might be, as I do not have much experience with Node and repl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use [`.load path_to_the_module`](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_commands_and_special_keys) command in the REPL console. To load modules in a file script, you need to use [`require('path_to_the_module')`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id).

So the first lines in the `transformscript.js` should be:

```js
require('./rdfMapping.js');
require('./rdfVocab.js');
```